# Editing form by double clicking element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form, and I want to be able to edit any part of that form by double clicking it. So going from this:

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Phone</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>John Smith</td>
  <td>johnsmith@gmail.com</td>
  <td>+12345678</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How can I by double-clicking an element, transform it to an input element?
For example: if I double click on `John Smith`, the HTML changes into this:

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Phone</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
   <td><input type="text" value="John Smith" name="name" /></td>
   <td>johnsmith@gmail.com</td>
   <td>+12345678</td>
  </form>
 </tr>
</table>
```

So now I can change John's name.

Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple may help

Comment: Why are you not wrapping the column values (`<td>`'s) in a `form` initially?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, fields from the second row are editable with dblclick

```js
document.querySelectorAll("table tr:nth-child(2) td").forEach(function(node){
 node.ondblclick=function(){
  var val=this.innerHTML;
  var input=document.createElement("input");
  input.value=val;
  input.onblur=function(){
   var val=this.value;
   this.parentNode.innerHTML=val;
  }
  this.innerHTML="";
  this.appendChild(input);
  input.focus();
 }
});
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Phone</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>John Smith</td>
  <td>johnsmith@gmail.com</td>
  <td>+12345678</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about that:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="name">John Smith</td>
        <td>johnsmith@gmail.com</td>
        <td>+12345678</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
$("#name").dblclick(function(e) {
    if (e.target.parentElement.nodeName != 'form') {
        var form = $('<form action="index.php" method="post">');
        var parent = $(e.target.parentElement);
        parent.children().each(function(i, elem){
            form.append(elem);
        })
        parent.empty();
        parent.append(form);
    }
})
</script>
```

It handles double click event and wraps all `<td>` elements inside `<tr>` into `<form>` tag.

Comment: You are missing the `<input>` tag here. Also, there is the possibility of multiple form elements being created

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    var haveForm = false;

    $("td").dblclick(function () {
        var thisVal = $(this).html();

        if (!haveForm) {
            $("td").wrapAll('<form action="index.php" method="post" />');
            haveForm = true;
        }
        $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + thisVal + '" name="name" />');
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxqne7x4/28/)

This makes use of jQuery's `wrapAll()` and safe guards against multiple `form` elements being created.